# get value of dropdown not just ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to populate a textfield with the value of whatever is in my dropdown box.  Now all I get right now is the ID for the selected item, first in the list is 1, etc.

I know its got to be something stupid that I am missing but I can't see it at the moment.

How do I get the value of the selected item, instead of the ID?

Here is what I have so far, #id_maturity_letter is the dropdown and #message_text is the textarea I am trying to populate.

```
$("#id_maturity_letter").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('#message_text').val($('#id_maturity_letter').val());
    $.getJSON('', {id:id}, function(json) {

    });

});
```

Comment: The code that you've given **will** give the **value** of the currently selected option (http://jsfiddle.net/ZESku/) you'll have to describe your problem more/ provide a working example (http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: `.val` does give you the value of the selected option: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/3Y9vR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, be sure that your html is created as you wish:

```
<select id='id_maturity_letter'>
   <option id='1' value='1'>one</option>
   <option id='2' value='2'>two</option>
   <option id='3' value='3'>three</option>
</select>
```

will of course return a value that is equal to the id

So if you need the text:

```
 $("#message_text").val( $("option:selected", this).text() );
```

Comment: thank you, this did the trick.  Once I can select this answer I will  (7 mins)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the text of the selected option instead of its value. If that's actually the case, you can match the selected `<option>` element with the [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector, then call [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) on the resulting object:

```
$("#id_maturity_letter").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $("#message_text").val($("option:selected", this).text());
});
```